# Derivation of odds ratios from logit equation parameters?

Tags: interpretation, logit, multinomial-logit, log-linear

I have been trying to understand how this interpretation works. For this I have used the article "Interpreting the Parameters of Loglinear Models" from Alba, but  I am really stuck.

I his article he derives the logit equations for a polytomous dependent variable (Intermarriage). So fa so good. The coefficients obtained are as follows:

[image]

but then Alba calculated the Odds ratios for Intermarriage (different versus same ancestry), by ancestry, cohort, generation and gender. I cannot figure out how he obtained the highlighted values. Anyone can explain/derive the values highlighted in red please?

[image]

I am sure there must be some easy explanation, but I wasn't able to figure it our.